# When is the inherited Constructor code called

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance, constructor, c++builder

If the constructor of my class inherits a parametrized constructor of another class, will that inherited constructor code be executed before or after the code that I place in my constructor?

For instance in this:

```
TCurrentKillerThread::TCurrentKillerThread() : TThread(true){
  CurrentKillerMutex = CreateMutex(NULL,true,NULL); // protect thread 
  try {
     Write("Created Current Killer");
  } __finally {
    ReleaseMutex(CurrentKillerMutex);
  }
  Start();
}
```

Would `TThread(true)` be executed before the code I have in `TCurrectKillerThread()`?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but `finally` is not standard C++, and is in fact rarely (never) needed: we usually use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to manage resources.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that finally is never needed.  It is a simple solution to memory leakage when exceptions are thrown.  But yeah, the __ clued me in to it being compiler specific.  Also, thanks for the formatting.

Comment: @Roberto : Smart pointers are a simple solution to memory leakage. C++ doesn't need `finally`.

Comment: Sure, it doesn't "need" finally.  But nor does it "need" smart pointers.  I personally don't see the need to pull in smart pointers when finally is so so easy.

Comment: @Roberto: it does need one or the other (or some other way to free locally allocated resources when an exception is thrown). But it doesn't need both, and personally I'd go with the one provided by the language, not some weird error-prone extension.

Comment: I don't know, I mean if you want the overhead of something like that I guess you could. But as builder just has __finally anyway, I don't see much of a reason to pull it in.  As far as it being error prone, it hasn't given us any problems in 20 something years.

Comment: @Roberto: sorry, I didn't realise what the "embarcadero" tag meant. If you're not developing in Standard C++, then of course you should use whatever practices are considered best in your language. I would still recommend RAII though; it's possible to forget to write a `finally` block, but impossible to forget to destroy a resource management object as it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The parent class is always initialized before the derived. You are not inheriting the constructor though - you're calling it.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Does anyone happen to know any problems with calling Start in the constructor of your class?  TThread breaks on the Start call in this code.

Comment: @Roberto: The Start is fine - at least given the code you've shown.

Comment: @Roberto: if `Start` is virtual, then calling it from a constructor will call the version defined in the class under construction, not the final override. If it is pure virtual, then calling it is an error giving undefined behaviour; most likely, it will either do nothing, or crash.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Borland (or whoever has c++builder now) TThread.Start isn't virtual IIRC - it'll spawn a thread calling the virtual Execute though. That shouldn't matter in the OP's case unless there's a subclass of `TCurrentKillerThread` he hasn't shown us.

Comment: Start() does in fact cause the program to crash with the exception "Cannot call Start on a running or suspended thread"  If you call Start() outside of the constructor, it works fine.  Though, I do have a subclass of TCurrentKillerThread.  This causes problems?

Comment: @Roberto: Aren't you creating the thread suspended? Wouldn't "Resume" be the right call? (Haven't used c++builder for years - this is OTOH)

Comment: Resume() does work.  However, we want to know why Start() doesn't.  Start() is supposed to be used to begin a thread that has been started in suspended mode.  However, if you call Start() inside teh constructor, it always throws the exception.

Comment: @Roberto: if there is a subclass that overrides `Execute` (assuming the code is using the framework Erik referred to), then you've got a world of trouble: a race condition between this thread constructing the object, and the new thread calling the virtual function that may not be finalised yet.

Comment: Hhm, my inherited class actually doesn't override execute.  Only TCurrentKillerThread overrides execute.

Comment: @Roberto: If you have a subclass of TCurrentKillerThread then you may be in trouble regardless - other virtuals perhaps? Something funny in vtable setup for Borland? The safe thing to do is to call Start outside the constructor - or open a c++builder specific question on this aspect of your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I may do that.  It almost looks like there is something in TThread to just prevent you from calling Start before the constructor has finished.

Comment: @Roberto: IIRC C++Builder does some weird stuff behind the scenes - e.g. preventing VCL instances on stack - so wouldn't surprise me if this was a compiler magic kind of check.

Comment: Yeah, could be.  Oddly enough, if I use our proprietary Threading class inside the constructor of TCurrentKillerThread and use that proprietary class to call the Start() function of the TCurrentKillerThread, it works fine and starts properly.

Comment: @Roberto: That really does sound like compiler magic. I'm going to avoid going on a rant why I left C++Builder though :P

Comment: "inherited" is jargon for "parent class" , in C++Builder and family. (Borrowed from Delphi)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, C++ construction works from the lowest base class to the most derived one.

Answer (score 0):

> Would TThread(true) be executed before the code I have in TCurrectKillerThread()?

Yes, `TThread(bool var){ .... }` is executed before `TCurrentKillerThread(){ .... }` when the derived class object is instantiated. Construction of parent class sub-object must take place before the derived class sub-object in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the constructor of base class is executed before the constructor of subclass, and destructor is executed from subclass to base class